# Is there a simple way to convert from a pull switch to a toggle switched light fixture?

Tags: electrical, lighting, bathroom, switch

I would like to replace a bathroom vanity light fixture in 100 year old house. It currently has a pull string on/off switch.  Is there a simple way to convert to a switched light fixture?  The switch can be located fixture.  How can I simply surface mount a switch for a new vanity light?

Comment: What does the sentence _"The switch can be located fixture."_ mean?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest-to-install solution to your issues is a length of 14/3 run in [surface raceway](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-500-Series-10-ft-Wire-Channel-V500/100207385?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal1_rr-_-202523808-_-100207385-_-N) and used as a switch loop.  You'll want a [circular raceway box](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-500-and-700-Series-4-3-4-in-Open-Base-Extension-Box-V5737/202276742?N=5yc1vZc65cZdf5) at the light fixture, and a [single gang raceway box at the switch](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-500-and-700-Series-Metallic-Switch-Box-V57240/202523808?N=5yc1vZc65cZdf5), by the way.

(Also note that the non-metallic raceway recommended by dfife's answer won't work here -- Legrand, for some reason, doesn't make round extension boxes for their non-metallic raceways, just for their metal ones.)

Diagram (originally appropriated for this Stack by Tester101 and reused here):

[image: diagram of switch loop wiring to current Code]

Answer (score 0):

Good question. There's a couple of options you have (if I understand your question correctly):

1. Tap into a power source (e.g., a receptacle), run the wire (typically behind the walls) to a switch, then run wire from the switch to the fixture. This is the standard approach (but may require an electrician). (See [how-to-wire-it](http://www.how-to-wire-it.com/wiring-a-2-way-switch.html) for examples of how to run the wire).
2. Tap into the power source and run the wire outside the wall and cover the wires with [raceway wire channels](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Wiremold-5-ft-Non-Metallic-Raceway-Wire-Channel-White-NMW1/100038290?N=5yc1vZc65e), to the lightswitch, then to the light.
3. Plug in to a receptacle and connect the same as #2.

Option 3 is easiest but most conspicuous. #1 isn't that hard, you just have to know what you're doing (lest ye die) and you may have to remove then subsequently repair drywall.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have attic access you can drill into the wall cavities from above and fish cable down to the fixture and to a new switch. For the switch, you'd use an "old work" electrical box, like the ones with tabs that open up and clamp against the back of the sheetrock (or lathe and plaster) when you tighten them.